# AVRO avdl file generation

Tags: java, hadoop, avro

I Defined a Person record as Avro IDL (*person.avdl*):

```
@namespace("net.tzolov.avro.extend")
protocol PersonProtocol {
    record Person {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
    }     
}
```

I am generating the java files, so this one is generating PersonProtocol.java and Person.java.
The PersonProtocol.java is empty file, is there a way I can exclude generating this file...

Answer (score 6):

You can't exclude the generation of this file because Avro IDL defines a **protocol** (see more [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/idl.html)).

Your *PersonProtocol.java* is empty because you don't use the RPCs that provides Avro IDL language.

For example:

```
@namespace("net.tzolov.avro.extend")
protocol PersonProtocol {
 record Person {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
 }

 string printMessage(string theMessage);    
}
```

By using the code generation, you will obtain this particular line which defines the RPC method :

```
void printMessage(java.lang.CharSequence theMessage, org.apache.avro.ipc.Callback<java.lang.CharSequence> callback) throws java.io.IOException;
```

If you just want to store data, you should use avro schema (avsc).